# How to replace a column in .fam with .txt in unix

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, plink-genomics

I am looking for some options in unix (may be awk or sed ) through which I can replace the last column in my .fam file with the last column (v8) of a .txt file. Something similar to the merge function in R.

My .fam file looks like this

```
20481 20481 0 0 2 -9
20483 20483 0 0 1 1
20488 20488 0 0 2 1
20492 20492 0 0 1 1
```

and my .txt file looks like this.

```
V1       V2     V3      V4      V6     V7_Pheno   V8
    2253792 20481   NA      DNA     1       Yes    2
    2253802 20483   NA      DNA     4       Yes    2
    2253816 20488   NA      DNA     0       No     1
    2253820 20492   NA      DNA     4       Yes    2
```

My outcome.fam file should looks like this

```
20481 20481 0 0 2 2
20483 20483 0 0 1 2
20488 20488 0 0 2 1
20492 20492 0 0 1 2
```

Comment: One has a header, one does not?

Answer (score 0):

- `paste` merges the lines
- `awk` allow you to select column, so

  ```
  paste foo.fam bar.txt | awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $13 }'
  ```

should do what you want

---

If you want to suppress the header line of `.txt` file, you can call `tail` to skip the first line:

`tail -n +2 bar.txt`

You can hence integrate it in you command line (assuming you use `bash`)

```
paste foo.fam <(tail -n +2 bar.txt) | awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $13 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can do it alone.

```
$: awk 'BEGIN{ getline < "f.txt" } 
     { gsub("[^ ]+$",""); l=$0; getline < "f.txt"; print l$7; }' f.fam
20481 20481 0 0 2 2
20483 20483 0 0 1 2
20488 20488 0 0 2 1
20492 20492 0 0 1 2
```

The `BEGIN` reads the header record on the `.txt`.
Then for each line of the `.fam`, strip off the last field and save to `l`.
`getline` used this way parses to fields also, so `print l$7;` prints the shortened record from `.fam` and adds the last field from `.txt`.